# How tightly can Marklogic search scores be controlled?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Our database contains documents with a lot of metadata, including relationships between those documents. Fictional example:

```
<document>
  <metadata>
    <document-number>ID 12345 : 2012</document-number>
    <publication-year>2012</publication-year>
    <cross-reference>ID 67890 : 1995</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 67890 : 1998</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 67891 : 2000</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 12345 : 2004</cross-reference>
    <supersedes>ID 12345 : 2004</supersedes>
    ...
  </metadata>
</document>
<document>
  <metadata>
    <document-number>ID 12345 : 2004</document-number>
    <publication-year>2004</publication-year>
    <cross-reference>ID 67890 : 1995</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 67890 : 1998</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 67891 : 2000</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 12345 : 2012</cross-reference>
    <cross-reference>ID 12345 : 2001</cross-reference>
    <superseded-by>ID 12345 : 2012</superseded-by>
    <supersedes>ID 12345 : 2001</supersedes>
    ...
  </metadata>
</document>
```

We're using a 1-box search, based on the Marklogic search api to allow users to search these documents. The search grammar describes a variety of contraints and search options, but mostly (and by default) they search by a field defined to include most of the metadata elements, with (somewhat) carefully chosen weights (what really matters here is that `document-number` has the highest weight.)

The problem is that the business wants quite specific ordering of results, and I can't think of a way to achieve it using the search api.

The requirement that's causing trouble is that if the user search matches a document number (say they search for "12345",) then all documents with that document number should be at the top of the result-set, ordered by descending date. It's easy enough to get them at the top of the result-set; `document-number` has the highest weight, so sorting by score works fine. The problem is that the secondary sort by date doesn't work because even though all the `document-number` matches have higher scores than other documents, they don't have the *same* score, so they end up ordered by how often the search term appears in the rest of the metadata; which isn't really meaningful at all.

What I think we really need is a way of having the search api score results simply by the highest weighted element that matches the search-term, without reference to any other matches in the document. I've had a look at the scoring algorithms and can't see one that does that; have I missed something or is this just not possible? Obviously, it doesn't have to be `score` that we order by; if there's some other way to get at the score of the single best match in a document and use it for sorting, that would be fine.

Is there some other solution I haven't even thought of?

I thought of doing two searches (one on `document-number`, and one on the whole metadata tree) and then combining the results, but that seems like it's going to cause a lot of pain with pagination and performance. Which sort-of defeats the purpose of using the search api in the first place.

I should add that it is correct to have those other matches in the result-set, so we can't just search only on `document-number`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've reached the limits of what the high-level search API can do for you. I have a few tricks to suggest, though. These won't be 100% robust, but they might be good enough for the business. Then you can get on with the application. Sorry if I sound cynical or dismissive, but I don't believe in micromanaging search results.

Simplest possible: re-sort the first page in memory. That first page could be a bit larger than the page you show to the user. Because it is still limited in size, you can make the rules for this fairly complex without suffering much. That would fix your 'descending date' problem. The results from page 1 wouldn't quite match up with page 2, but that might be good enough.

Taking the next step in complexity, consider using document-quality to handle the descending-date issue. This approach is used by http://markmail.org among others. As each document is inserted or updated, set document quality using a number derived from the date. This could be days or weeks or months since 1970, or using some other fixed date. Newer results will tend to float to the top. If any other boosts tend to swamp the date-based boost, you might get close to what you want.

There might also be some use in analyzing the query to extract the potentially boosting terms. If necessary you could then begin a recursive run of `xdmp:exists(cts:search(doc(), $query))` on each boosting term as if it were a standalone query. Bail out as soon as you find a `true()` result: that means you are going to boost that query term with an absurdly high weight to make it float to the top.

Once you know what the boosting term is, rewrite the entire query to set all other term weights to much lower values, perhaps even 0. The lower the weight, the less those non-boosting terms will interfere with the date-based quality and the boosting weight. If there is no boosting term, you might want make other adjustments. All this is less expensive than it sounds, by the way. Aside from the `xdmp:exists` calls, it's just in-memory expression evaluation.

Again, though, these are all just tricks to nudge the scores. They won't give you the absolute control over ranking that you're looking for. In my experience, attempts to micromanage scores are doomed to failure. My bet is that your users would be happier with raw TF/IDF, whatever your business managers say.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to use two searches, as you suggest. Put a range index on document-number (and ideally the document date), extract any potential document-number values from the query (`search:parse`, extract, then `search:resolve` is a good strategy), then execute a cts:element-range-query for docs matching those document-number values with date descending. If there aren't enough results to fill up your N-result page, then get the next N-x results from search api. You can keep track of the documents that were returned in the first result set and exclude those URIs from the second one. Keeping track of the pagination won't be too bad.

This might not perform as well as the first solution, but the time difference for the additional range index query combined with a shorter search api query should be negligible enough for most.